# How to access hexadecimal List in Python?

Tags: python

I want to use a list of hexadecimal numbers.

**Why does rnd1 always == 0?** 
In this case it should equal position 1 of rn_table, which is 6.

Also, changing the print type to %x (for hex) gives this error: 
"Type error: %x format: a number is required, not list" - I'm using numbers, but I suppose this means I cannot use a list? In this case what should I use instead of a list?

```
cluck = 16
clevel = 12
enemy_level = 10

rn_table = [0x63, 0x06, 0xF0, 0x23, 0xF8, 0xE5, 0xA8, 0x01, 0xC1, 0xAE, 0x7F, 0x48,
0x7B, 0xB1, 0xDC, 0x09, 0x22, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0xEE, 0x9D, 0x58, 0xD5, 0x55, 0x24, 0x39, 0x7A, 0xDF,
0x8E, 0x54, 0x6C, 0x1B, 0xC0, 0x0B, 0xD0, 0x43, 0xD8, 0x9A, 0x47, 0x5D, 0x21, 0x02, 0x17, 0x4B,
0xDB, 0x11, 0xAF, 0x70, 0xCD, 0x4D, 0x34, 0x49, 0x72, 0x91, 0x2D, 0x62, 0x97, 0x59, 0x45, 0xF7,
0x6E, 0x46, 0xAA, 0x0A, 0xA3, 0xC8, 0x31, 0x92, 0x38, 0xFA, 0xD4, 0xE6, 0xCB, 0xF3, 0xDE, 0x6B,
0xBB, 0xF1, 0x1C, 0x3C, 0xD6, 0xAD, 0xB2, 0xA9, 0xDD, 0x57, 0x42, 0x95, 0x0C, 0x79, 0x25, 0x1F,
0xBC, 0xE7, 0xAC, 0x5B, 0x83, 0x28, 0x76, 0xF2, 0x18, 0xDA, 0x87, 0xA1, 0x61, 0x6F, 0xBE, 0x5A,
0x5E, 0x51, 0xEF, 0xB0, 0xC9, 0x15, 0x74, 0x89, 0xBD, 0xD1, 0xA2, 0x75, 0xD7, 0x99, 0x85, 0x4C,
0x4F, 0xD2, 0xBF, 0x4A, 0x20, 0x08, 0x56, 0xA0, 0x50, 0x3A, 0x67, 0x26, 0x41, 0x33, 0xB7, 0xBA,
0xFB, 0x30, 0xCF, 0x7C, 0x84, 0x2C, 0x32, 0xE9, 0x1D, 0x16, 0x82, 0x78, 0xA4, 0x80, 0x65, 0x5F,
0x0E, 0x27, 0xB9, 0x19, 0xC3, 0xA7, 0xB6, 0x00, 0x3B, 0xFC, 0x88, 0xE1, 0xC6, 0x93, 0xFE, 0x8B,
0xD9, 0xB8, 0x13, 0x69, 0x2F, 0x64, 0x12, 0x37, 0xFD, 0x77, 0xE2, 0xB5, 0x04, 0xE0, 0x1A, 0x8C,
0x8F, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xF9, 0x60, 0xEB, 0x29, 0xE3, 0x90, 0xA5, 0x68, 0x3D, 0x81, 0x73, 0x3F, 0xAB,
0x7E, 0xB3, 0x0F, 0xCE, 0xC4, 0x35, 0x94, 0x96, 0x86, 0x71, 0xD3, 0x2A, 0xE4, 0x9F, 0x9C, 0xEC,
0x4E, 0x14, 0xF5, 0xEA, 0x40, 0xA6, 0xF6, 0x03, 0x98, 0xC5, 0x07, 0xF4, 0x2B, 0xC2, 0x3E, 0xE8,
0x9B, 0x36, 0x53, 0x2E, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0x52, 0x10, 0x66, 0x1E, 0xED, 0x8A, 0x44, 0x9E, 0x05, 0xFF,
0x5C, 0xC7, 0x6A, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x12, 0x19, 0x21, 0x27, 0x2D, 0x35, 0x3D, 0x49, 0x51, 0x5A,
0x62, 0x69, 0x72, 0x7A, 0x83, 0x8B, 0x94, 0x9D, 0xA5, 0xAB, 0xB2, 0xB9, 0xC1, 0xC9, 0xD2, 0xD9,
0xDE, 0xE3, 0xE8, 0xED, 0xF5]

lookups = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
index = 0
dword_C06748 = 0

count = 0
rnd1 = 0

index1 = 0
offset1 = 0

def next_value():
    global lookups, index, count, rnd1, index1
    while count < 1:
        index1 = index + 1
        rnd1 = rn_table[0]
        lookups[index] += 1
        index = index + 1 & 7
        count += 1

next_value()
print "in: %r  cnt: %r  rnd1: %r lookups: %r \t offset1: %r" % (index, count, rnd1, lookups, offset1)
```

Comment: `index + 1 & 7` - please add parentheses. Nobody wants to lookup the operator precedence when reading your code. In this case it's obvious you mean `(index + 1) & 7` but I'm sure most people will not know for sure if that's what your code does.

Comment: `rnd1` equals 99 after running your code.  It runs the loop only once because `count` goes to `1`, and anyway, it always looks at `rn_table[0]`.

Comment: Where did "Close: Too localised" go?  Anyway, voting to close for that reason.

Comment: @RichieHindle but when I run my code it says rnd1 = 0 always. No matter what I set rn_table[x] to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only do two things to `rnd1`:

```
rnd1 = 0
```

and

```
rnd1 = rn_table[0]
```

The second sets `rnd1` to 0x63, which is 99.

I don't get the error you mention when I change the print type to %x.

Comment: For some reason cmd.exe was not running an up-to-date version of my py script. I don't know why it does that. So rnd1 was always == 0.

I've fixed it now. And no errors. Thanks.